# What have differential equations to do with differentiation.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Differential equations such as

> $$y^{''}+p(x)y^{'}+q(x)y=g(x)$$

have derivative sign. What do these have to do with derivatives? I do not see limits incorporated into definition of differentiation equations. Am I missing something?

Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

You have an equation in terms of a function and its derivatives. Hence, differential equation.